# Tokens and values upon requests

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, fiddler, devtools

I'm trying to understand what these tokens/values are upon running requests via python/fiddler on a YouTube channel ajax comments.
Does anyone know what they mean?

"PBJ"?

"ctoken"?

"itct"?

"session_token"/"xsrf"? (they seem to be identical)

[image]

Comment: I see absolutely no Python here...

Comment: @pstatix Sorry my question wasn't "Can you tell me if there is any Python?" If it was, I wouldn't need to ask.

Comment: why do you use tag `python-requests` if there is no python code in your question.

Comment: as for `xsrf` see wikipedia [Cross-site request forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). It is for security. Other field can be also for security. Or they inform what element you want to watch. I susspect they rather aren't for SEO or statistics.

Comment: @furas This is a request response. Query strings are involved when dealing with python-requests as it was used to obtain this response. I don't mind changing the tags if you could provide me with better tags.

Comment: The same strings you can get in `DevTools` in `Chrome/Firefox` or local proxy server [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) or [mitmproxy](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/latest/mitmproxy.html) and many other tools - so maybe you should add tags for those tools too.